# Can I (and if so, how do I) change default settings in Nokia Pro Cam

Tags: lumia, settings, camera

Each time I enter the Nokia Pro Cam all settings (white balance, ISO, shutter speed, ...) are set to "auto". Is there a way that I can change that, so that I can have it to default to, say, daylight white balance, ISO 200 and -1 exposure?

Comment: From the main screen, swipe left, go to "Settings".  Swipe left to "Applications", then down to the Camera Pro.  From there you should be able to change the defaults.

Comment: Camera Pro doesn't show in that list. The only related thing I find is "photos+camera", and that one does not contain those settings.

Comment: I just installed Nokia Camera on my 920 and it seems I can change the default settings from the app itself by clicking the "..." then touching "Settings".  When I hit save there, the settings take effect for all future shots.

Comment: @MaxVernon I get the feeling that you actually describe the settings for the build-in Windows Phone camera app rather than the nokia one? The settings view of Nokia Pro Cam doesn't have a save button.

Comment: I shouldn't have said "hit save" - just exiting the settings screen saves the settings.  And no, I'm not talking about the built-in app.  I'm talking about the Nokia Camera app that lets you customize the shutter speed, white balance, etc, that has the bracketing feature...

Comment: OK, that's interesting: I have no exposure related settings there at all (only stuff like Framing grids, Aspect ratio and such). Sounds like my app is a bit off: should probably try to remove it and re-install and see what happens. Thanks for your help so far @MaxVernon :-)

Comment: Hmmm... perhaps we are talking about two different apps.  I downloaded mine from the store by searching for Nokia Camera.  You can see the app here (assuming you are signed in to the app store):  http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/nokia-camera/bfd2d954-12da-415c-ad99-69a20f101e04

Answer (score 1):

Currently, it is not possible to save the settings you mentioned for the next shooting session.

However, you could send your suggestion as feedback to the team:
[Nokia Beta Labs / Nokia Camera beta](https://betalabs.nokia.com/trials/Nokia-Camera-beta)